What role does Classical Logic play in good reasoning?
I’m going to take a moderate pluralist view of Logic for this post. That is, I am assuming that there are different logics for different purposes, as we can use then in their different respects without logical difficulty. It is not contradictory to use Linear Logic at the burger shop vs. using Classical Logic in math class.
This brings me to my question: what role does (or should) Classical Logic play in ordinary reasoning? Considering that many situations require intensional operators, is Classical Logic a sort of “home base” for reasoning from which we can go on to other frameworks? Is Classical Logic on its own mainly useful in mathematics?

Since classical logic does not include modal operators or abductions it does not apply when those are used. However, the real question is how it fares when it does apply. Due to paradoxes of material implication and the like it does not reflect natural reasoning fully. Sometimes this is undesirable (it ignores relevance, for example), but often it is for the better (natural reasoning is not the gold standard of precision). It gives precisely what can be claimed without fearing counterexamples, hence prominence in mathematics.

I'm going to avoid the terms 'logic' and 'reasoning' for a moment, because these terms are frequently misunderstood, and tend to create more heat than light. Bear with me…
With that in mind, let's begin by noting that most human linguistic production is in the narrative mode. We tell stories about what we did or other people did, about what's happening in the world, about who we like and dislike, etc. Narratives are an effective mode of communication, particularly with respect to the social, cultural, and emotional/interpersonal situations that we embed ourselves in. But narratives have their limits: they are subjective, biased in various ways, and tend to evolve/change over time as our understanding of social contexts changes. Something we talk about quite proudly when we're 20 we might talk about quite ruefully when we're 30, if you follow my meaning…
This exposes a need for some more rigorous, stable, and exacting mode of linguistic production, something that establishes a more defined syntax structure and a systematic process of connecting and transforming utterances. This is decidedly not natural for human linguistics. It's a skill we have to develop over time and with effort. The simplest (and likely earliest) form of this is jargon, the kind of specialized shorthand language that every kind of workman (from plumbers to coders) learns in the course of their work. What jargon does is fix actions and relationships outside of narrative. Rather than saying "what I do is take this thing and place it on the end of that thing and turn it counter-clockwise" (a narrative) jargon might say "the widget screws into the dongle". It's this moment of depersonalization that makes jargon so powerful.
Over the ages people have put a lot of effort into making more abstract and depersonalized modes of language, usually for practical purposes to begin with, but then because abstract and depersonalized modes of language become powerful tools for the act of thinking and speaking in itself. Classical logic and mathematics are two such language modes, powerful tools for addressing problems and issues that cannot be resolved in narrative modes.
When we ask: "what role does (or should) Classical Logic play in ordinary reasoning?" the question sort of misses the point. 'Reasoning' means bringing the power of narrative and abstract/depersonalized modes together. We naturally 'rationalize' our narrative productions as time goes by, because we learn to see things in new ways. By working with more abstract and depersonalized modes we can rationalize our narratives more deeply.

+1 From an empiricist, or a naturalist or a pragmatic point of view, this is imo the only sensible approach. Logic as normative science needs to be seen as part of rational decision making. It's a pity many text books on logic skip that kind of preamble. A rare exception: Josh Dever's https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/f642l3nk4cd8kk7cy1p88/LogicBook-Draft-of-18-5-31.pdf

+1 That's a good story!

"Ordinary reasoning" makes little use of any formal logic. It's based on heuristics of what usually worked in the past. It goes like this: "In condition A, thinking in manner X was helpful in the past. We are now dealing with a condition similar to A. So, we will try thinking in manner X." No part of this involves formal deductions. Both A and X are huge patterns of neural activations, not neat little propositions.
Your brain is a massive, continuous-weighted, randomized neural network, highly tolerant to faults and damage. Formal deduction involves a small number of axioms, works with discrete propositions, deals only with logical necessity, and will completely break if given a single false proposition. They are deeply contrasting paradigms.
There is little we can say about the real world that follows as a matter of pure deduction. We cannot deductively predict what will result from any physical situation; our judgments about this are heuristic and inductive. "It worked that way in the past, so I suppose it will probably do it again." Deduction is used to make predictions about idealized models of physical situations. These models sometimes may be applicable to real situations, but in doing so there is always going to be the possibility of error, where the real world doesn't match the model.
GOFAI (Good Old-Fashioned AI) often involves modeling the world using propositions about it, from which the computer makes logical deductions. If deductive logic really worked for everyday situations, this approach would have been very successful. But what we've seen, instead, is that GOFAI works on simple toy scenarios or in factories where it will only encounter carefully controlled situations, and has great difficulty with the real world. The real world is full of edge cases that make the GOFAI's "logical deductions" incorrect.
There have been attempts to make logic more flexible, with defeasible reasoning. But this does not work that well. It's still a human writing the logical rules, which drastically limits the size of the model. And a lot of the world just doesn't map that neatly onto logical propositions. It's much more effective, in practice, for AI researchers to mimic some of what the brain does: tweak the weights of a huge neural network until its behavior is approximately what you wanted.
Not to say these neural networks are really brain-like; they aren't. There's a lot about human thinking they fail to capture. But they are more brain-like than GOFAI, and they do tend to be vastly more capable than GOFAI programs in the same domains. ML translation > GOFAI translation; ML text to speech > GOFAI text to speech; ML image generation > GOFAI image generation; ML chess playing > GOFAI chess playing; ML common-sense reasoning > GOFAI common-sense reasoning; and so on. The areas where GOFAI still has a hold tend to be relatively simple domains where it's important for a human to be able to interpret why the machine made its judgment.
